# Select rows from query table

Tags: ssms-2014

Is there an add-in for SSMS 2014 that would allow me to right click on a table form my joins to do the select top 1000 rows functionality?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out an even better way of doing this. It's better because you don't need to install anything on top of SSMS and you don't need to touch the mouse to use it.

```
Options > Environment > Keyboard > Query Shortcuts
```

You can then create a key binding to a small query. once you create the key binding you can then highlight the table name from the query editor and trigger the binding to do the select. SSMS is smart enough to insert the highlighted table as your `from` clause.

[image]